# Get unique groups from a list

Tags: python, list, algorithm, set, combinations

I am trying to create an algoritm to create unique groups of length = N from a list L with len(L) values.

**EDIT: Unique group is the one, where any of the values has never been with any of the values in a group before.**

**EDIT: So if instead of values we would have people, anyone in the group should always meet only new people in the new group.**

Say we have a list L and try to find unique groups of 4:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
N = 4

unique_groups = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]
len(unique_groups) = 2
```

So here we have 8 values and 2 unique groups, any new group would contain at least one value which is contained in previous one, e.g. [1,2,3,5] or [1,3,5,7] contain at least two values from before, so these groups are not unique.

Where len(L) = 12, we have 3 different groups, while len(L) >= 16 gives us way more options:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
N = 4

unique_groups = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16], [1,5,9,13], [2,3,7,12] ...]
len(unique_groups) = ?
```

I have tried few unintuitive and slow approaches, namely comparing all combinations, which should take a lot of time if length of list gets bigger.
This is one of the approaches:

```
def findsubsets(s, n):
    return list(itertools.combinations(s, n))


s = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]


sets = findsubsets(s,4)

sets_unique = []


def compare_sets(set1, set2):
    init_eq = 0
    for s1 in set1:
        if s1 in set2 and init_eq > 0:
            return False
        elif s1 in set2 and init_eq < 1:
            init_eq += 1
        else:
            continue
    return True


for s in sets:
    start_point = sets.index(s)
    print(start_point)
    for i in range(start_point + 1, len(sets) + 1):
        set2 = sets[i]
        if compare_sets(s, set2):
            print(s, set2)
            sets_unique.append(set2)

print(sets_unique)
```

EDIT2: Real life problem of this, is to match employees in a group of N, so these groups never contain two same people. Every person should meet only new people.

Comment: Why `[5,6,7,8]` and `[1,5,9,13]` are unique? Don't they contain some elements in common?

Comment: are you creating combination of list elements ?

Comment: I have poorly stated what I mean by unique. It must be a group, where values 'never met' eachother in a group before. So @DaniMesejo, these two groups are unique because 5 has been only with 6,7,8 and then with 1,9,13

Answer (score 1):

Your question update is quite clear now; thanks.

This problem is isomorphic to sets of points and lines in a [projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane).  You are trying to construct as many lines as you can with `N` points on each line.  Look under the subsection "A finite example" for a visualization of the process, and "Vector space construction" for the formal algorithm.

To give you an idea here you will begin at an arbitrarily chosen point`1`.  Make sets (colinear points) by appending (conveniently) consecutive, disjoint triples:

```
1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7
1  8  9 10
1 11 12 13
...
```

This gives you all groups containing point 1.  Now comes the mathematically interesting part: how you cross-link the points 2 and higher will define a `projective plane`; the solution from here is not unique.  One standard algorithm searches for a homeomorphic solution, a greedy algorithm: at each choice point, choose the lowest numbered point that is legal for the current open slot.
This will give us

```
2  5  8 11
2  6  9 12
2  7 10 13
...
3  5  9 13
3  6 10 11
```

et cetera

You will need to define whether you want *all* possible distinct solutions, or merely the first one you can find.  Each distinct solution defines a different projective plane topology.

Dealing with this from a standpoint of projective planes has you start with *affines* and derive the planes from there.  Esepcially check out the three properties of an **affine plane**

Additional references:
http://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/47-Fano/mathgames_05_30_06.html

Does that give you enough to play with for now?